# Proper work with incoming mail

Tags: civimail, joomla

Already mastered the system. Faced problems, but not here they helped to solve them, for which many thanks.
There was another question, the answer to which I can not find anywhere else.

1) I set up work with incoming mail, but all the letters go to the “Actions” tab, in the client's card. So it should be? Shouldn't they go to the "Newsletters" tab?

2) Where can I read about the organization of work with incoming mail? What is the best way to work with him so that it is most convenient? Are there any real examples of the organization of such work?

3) Is there some kind of Russian-language help, or forum?

Postscript I apologize if someone asked such questions somewhere. I do not know English, because it is difficult for me to understand a huge amount of information.
Give thanks!

Comment: Hi Вася - you are doing really well and i appreciate the language problems. A couple of comments. Best to only ask one question per 'question. I don't konw of other russion-language users. sorry. i know agiliway.com are ukraine based, but i don't presume to know about the language similarities and appreciate there are political tensions between the two countries

Comment: Thanks for this information!
I did not know that they are based in Ukraine.
Ukraine is a Russian-speaking country. I think someone will answer my questions if I write them in Russian))

Comment: Most SE CiviCRM folk have English as their first language - so you get a wider pool of folk to answer if you can convey the problem in english. You can also ask others like me to help you find the best words to explain the problem then others may be able to help with the answer. Also check the terminology in an english version of civicrm to avoid confusion like 'action tab' v 'activities tab'. if it is easier, just do this by testing on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org (assuming nobody has changed its languate to korean ;-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newsletter tab would be for outgoing bulk mailings ie civimail.

Activities tab (what you translated above as Actions tab) is where incoming mail goes because they are created as an Activity.

Comment: Tank you friend!

Answer (score 1):

On the Russian-language part, on https://chat.civicrm.org/ there are currently French and Dutch channels so I don't see why you couldn't create a Russian one.  I don't whether there are any other Russian speakers who would join the channel, but you could be the first.  As Pete said, most of us speak English as our first (or only!) language so if you put it in English there are more people who may be able to help.

Are you on a multi-language site (ie using Russian and other languages), or a single-language site in Russian?
Multi-language is configured on Настройки - Локализация
[image]

If you are on multi-language then if you temporarily switch to English using the language switcher block when you do screen shots that would help us.

If you are on a single-language site, then there is a new feature that has just been merged (I'm not sure whether it will be in 5.9 or 5.10) that will let you do the same thing and switch to English without affecting other users.

Comment: No. My site is a a single-language in Russian.